# How to make web applications look exactly like desktop applications?

Tags: php, web-applications, user-interface, web

I was wondering if there is a definitive solution for building web applications that looks like desktop applications, for corporative users that are used to windows. I MEAN THE GUI DESKTOP PERSPECTIVE.

Can anyone help me with that? I use PHP.

I am in a group developing an application that will work for a bank, and that must look exactly like an application so the users do not even notice it is a web based one for security reasons (informed by the bank holder).

We have tried to use Java Applet, but it took just too much time to load, as the application is very big.

Comment: I don't think PHP would have anything to do with it. Your problem is on the client's layer, not in the server layer.

Comment: I have an answers for that: qooxdoo is a JS framework that can use any language (including PHP) in the Server Side, and have many components and layouts to make your web project look exactly like a Windows Application. Look those great demos: http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/widgetbrowser/

Comment: I like this ExtJS and qooxdoo, I did not know of their existence. You should put your answer in details. :)

Comment: When is my question be liberated?

Comment: **New url of qoodoo js framework**: https://qooxdoo.org/qxl.widgetbrowser/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ExtJs for your front end and php as back-end.ExtJs is a javascript framework for web-application. 
http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/

Comment: Naresh is a contributor to ExtJS. Take that as you will.

Comment: Thank you Naresh. This lib works just fine!

Answer (score 2):

I can't recommend PHP for anything personally, so here are some others...

Silverlight is a pretty good start. Does that even count as a web app?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight

SharePoint is a better alternative, being a Microsoft product.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint

On a subjective note, the internet is so pervasive now that just writing a friendly web page should be enough. Everyone uses the internet and can usually figure things out that present the format nicely.

What data will your application be serving? That has a big part in what framework you pick.

Comment: IMHO, he shouldn't use Microsoft tech unless he has lots of money to expend on that. He will have to pay for SharePoint and Windows Server and do not expect the site to work on many devices and operational systems (iPhone, iPad, Linux etc.)

Comment: @EASI "corperate", "bank". Words that smell of money. Concerning mobile devices, why is windows UX important on mobile? This question is outmoded imo.